# Insert multiple data and multiple image Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I have 3 tables in laravel like this

table **motor**

- id_motor (increment)
- motor_tag
- motor_name

table **rekap**

- id_rekap (increment)
- id_user
- tgl

table **rekap_motor**

- id_rekap_motor (increment)
- id_rekap (FK from table **rekap**)
- id_motor (FK from table **motor**)
- frekwensi
- arus
- daya
- temperatur
- image (nullable)

When i save foreach data to table **rekap_motor** based on **id_motor** displaying, all data stored to table, except image that can't be saved.

This is my controller and my view

**Controller**

```
// Save to Table Rekap
$rekap              =   new Rekap;
$rekap->id_user     =   Auth::user()->id;
$rekap->tgl         =   $request->tgl;
$rekap->save();

// Save to Table Rekap_motor
foreach ($request->id_motor as $key => $value) {
   $rekap_motor                =   new Rekap_motor;
   $rekap_motor->id_rekap      =   $rekap->id_rekap;
   $rekap_motor->id_motor      =   $request->id_motor[$key];
   $rekap_motor->frekwensi     =   $request->frekwensi[$key];
   $rekap_motor->arus          =   $request->arus[$key];
   $rekap_motor->daya          =   $request->daya[$key];
   $rekap_motor->temperatur    =   $request->temperatur[$key];

   if($request->hasfile('image')) {
      foreach ($request->file('image') as $images) {
           $name   = 'motor_' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $image->move(public_path('/upload/'), $name);
           $data[] =   implode(", ", $name);

           $rekap_motor->image =   $data;
      }
   }
   $rekap_motor->save();
 }
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('rekap_bardi.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <label>Tanggal</label>
                        <input type="date" class="@error('tgl') is-invalid @enderror" name="tgl" value="{{ old('tgl') }}" required>
                        @error('tgl')
                            {{ $message }}
                        @enderror

                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Motor Tag</th>
                                <th>Name of Motor</th>
                                <th>Frekwensi</th>
                                <th>>Arus</th>
                                <th>Daya</th>
                                <th>Temperatur</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach($motor as $row)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id_motor[{{ $row->id_motor }}]" value="{{ $row->id_motor }}">
                                        {{ $row->motor_tag }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ $row->motor_name }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="frekwensi[{{ $row->id_motor }}]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="arus[{{ $row->id_motor }}]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="daya[{{ $row->id_motor }}]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="temperatur[{{ $row->id_motor }}]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="file" name="image[{{ $row->id_motor }]" multiple>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>

                        <button type="submit">Simpan</button>
                    </form>
```

How to fix this my issue? Sorry my english is bad.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way I found to save images is to use Spatie Media Lybrary package.
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction

In this way, you don't even need an image field in your model.

And the package allows you also to deal with multiple images.